# SQL: Create an extra column with last 3 days date as a value

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I have a table(users) with these sample data

```
user    location     name
111      usa          aaa
222      canada       bbb
333      usa          ccc
444      mexico       ddd
555      japan        eee
```

From this table, i want to get the final output like below

```
date               user    location     name
2020-11-03         111      usa          aaa
2020-11-03         222      canada       bbb
2020-11-03         333      usa          ccc
2020-11-03         444      mexico       ddd
2020-11-03         555      japan        eee
2020-11-02         111      usa          aaa
2020-11-02         222      canada       bbb
2020-11-02         333      usa          ccc
2020-11-02         444      mexico       ddd
2020-11-02         555      japan        eee
2020-11-01         111      usa          aaa
2020-11-01         222      canada       bbb
2020-11-01         333      usa          ccc
2020-11-01         444      mexico       ddd
2020-11-01         555      japan        eee
```

if you see above output, for each day(last 3 days), i am seeing `user,location,name` data.

**Can anyone suggest a solution for this**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want a `cross join`:

```
select v.date, t.*
from t cross join
     (values ('2020-11-03'), ('2020-11-02'), ('2020-11-01')) v(date);
```

You can easily adapt this for the last three days:

```
select current_date - v.n * interval '1 day', t.*
from t cross join
     (values (1), (2), (3)) v(n);
```

Comment: i don't want to manually provide date values why because if i want last 30days data. it is not a good practice to provide all 30 days dates manually

Comment: is there any other approach for last `n` days without hardcoding anything?

Comment: @siva . . . You just need to generate a series.  You can use a calendar table, a tally table, *any* table, or funky array stuff.